# Complicated ruby inject method

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

Can't seem to figure this out. Please help me understand what this code is requesting for regarding `a` variable and what the intended output is supposed to be. Thanks in advance!

```
def function_name(a)
  a.inject({}){ |a,b| a[b] = a[b].to_i + 1; a}.\
  reject{ |a,b| b == 1 }.keys
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `a` is an array,

The function first count the occurrences of the keys.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']
a.inject({}) { |a,b|
  # a: a result hash, this is initially an empty hash (`{}` passed to inject)
  # b: each element of the array.
  a[b] = a[b].to_i + 1 # Increase count of the item
  a # The return value of this block is used as `a` argument of the block
    #   in the next iteration.
}
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}
```

Then, it filter items that occur multiple times:

```
...reject{ |a,b|
  # a: key of the hash entry, b: value of the hash entry (count)
  b == 1 # entry that match this condition (occurred only once) is filtered out.
}.keys
# => ["b"]
```

So, function names like `get_duplicated_items` should be used instead of `function_name` to better describe the purpose.

Comment: Thanks! This has helped. I have one more related question. What is the period at the end of the block? "a}`.`" I find that if I don't include this that the method fails.

Comment: @LelandSmith, The `reject` here returns a hash.  `.keys` was used to get only keys of the hash. (`.` to call method `keys`)

Comment: Sorry @falsetru I am referring to the . at the end of `_i + 1; a}.`  
Once again thank you for your help!

Comment: @LelandSmith, It's same for the `reject` method. Trailing backslash(`\ `) is for line continuation.

Answer (score 1):

It wants a to be an array, but it doesn't seem to matter what the array is made up of so you'll need some other clue to know what should be in the array.

What the code does is fairly straight foreword. For each item in the array it uses it as a key in a hash. It then basically counts how many times it sees that key. Finally it removes all of the items that only showed up once.

It returns the unique items in the array `a` that show up 2 or more times.